# How to run jenkins as a different user

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I have been trying to follow tutorials and this one: [Deploy as Jenkins User or Allow Jenkins To Run As Different User?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948224/deploy-as-jenkins-user-or-allow-jenkins-to-run-as-different-user)

but I still can't for the love of the computing gods, run as a different user. Here are the steps of what I did:

1. download the macosx pkg for jenkins(LTS)
2. setup plugins etc and git
3. try to build it

I keep getting a can't clone error because jenkins keeps starting as anonymous:

```
Started by user anonymous
```

How do I set it up so that jenkins runs as me? I was using the jenkins web UI so it was in localhost:8080

I tried logging in also using /login but I can't even login using my name or as root.

The people tab doesn't even have a create user link, so yeah I've been stuck. Help please?

Comment: setting up jenkins as another user turned out to be too painful for me. it meant codesign-provisioning-keychain-hell. I switched to using jenkins-app as sti suggested below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9831634/300694

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**ISSUE 1:**

`Started by user anonymous`

That **does not** mean that Jenkins started as an anonymous user.

It just means that the person who started the build was not logged in. If you enable Jenkins security, you can create usernames for people and when they log in, the

```
"Started by anonymous"
```

will change to

```
"Started by < username >".
```

**Note: You do not have to enable security in order to run jenkins or to clone correctly.**

If you want to enable security and create users, you should see the options at `Manage Jenkins > Configure System`.

---

**ISSUE 2:**

The "can't clone" error is a different issue altogether. It has nothing to do with you logging in to jenkins or enabling security. It just means that Jenkins does not have the credentials to clone from your git SCM.

Check out [the Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) to see how to set up Jenkins to work with your git repository.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that was what i was reading but then I was totally dumbfounded on how to set the user to myself, as apparently it was running as "daemon". I finally figured it out when i sort of clicked the "started by anonymous"(anonymous was a link) and it sent me to the user setup screen. i guess the UI is just not stupid friendly :P thanks for the tip!

Comment: @sti has a great solution - see 'jenkins-app' below.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 44):

The "Issue 2" answer given by @Sagar works for the majority of git servers such as gitorious.

However, there will be a name clash in a system like *gitolite* where the public ssh keys are checked in as files named with the username, ie `keydir/jenkins.pub`. What if there are multiple jenkins servers that need to access the same gitolite server?

(Note: this is about running the Jenkins daemon not running a build job as a user (addressed by @Sagar's "Issue 1").)

So in this case you do need to run the Jenkins daemon as a different user.

There are two steps:

#### Step 1

The main thing is to update the `JENKINS_USER` environment variable. Here's a patch showing how to change the user to `ptran`.

BEGIN PATCH

```
--- etc/default/jenkins.old     2011-10-28 17:46:54.410305099 -0700
+++ etc/default/jenkins 2011-10-28 17:47:01.670369300 -0700
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@
 PIDFILE=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid

 # user id to be invoked as (otherwise will run as root; not wise!)
-JENKINS_USER=jenkins
+JENKINS_USER=ptran

 # location of the jenkins war file
 JENKINS_WAR=/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
--- etc/init.d/jenkins.old      2011-10-28 17:47:20.878539172 -0700
+++ etc/init.d/jenkins  2011-10-28 17:47:47.510774714 -0700
@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@

 #DAEMON=$JENKINS_SH
 DAEMON=/usr/bin/daemon
-DAEMON_ARGS="--name=$NAME --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME --output=$JENKINS_LOG -   -pidfile=$PIDFILE" 
+DAEMON_ARGS="--name=$JENKINS_USER --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME --output=$JENKINS_LOG --pidfile=$PIDFILE" 

 SU=/bin/su
```

END PATCH

#### Step 2

Update ownership of jenkins directories:

```
chown -R ptran /var/log/jenkins
chown -R ptran /var/lib/jenkins
chown -R ptran /var/run/jenkins
chown -R ptran /var/cache/jenkins
```

#### Step 3

Restart jenkins

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I have exactly the same problem, but I have it installed on redhat and the only thing that I have is the /etc/init.d/jenkins and the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins (is an xml file) would u advice to do as you have above shown for users on redhat too?

Comment: @7dr3am7: I can't say for sure, my company standardized on Ubuntu so I haven't been on a RedHat system for quite some time.

Does the `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` look like this
: [jenkins.sysconfig.in](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/rpm/SOURCES/jenkins.sysconfig.in) ?

If so then you can try updating the JENKINS_USER variable and then update `/etc/init.d/jenkins` similar to my patch above.

Comment: Hi Peter! Yes, that is what I am looking for! Last question: Do I need to give the pwd of the user too? (Which it does seem legitimate)

Comment: @7dr3am7: No, I was able to do this without needing the password of the user ('ptran' in my example).

Comment: Hi Peter, regarding "I was not able to do this via Manage Jenkins > Configure System as suggested in @Sagar's "Issue 1", I was talking about running a build job as a user, not the Jenkins daemon. If you see issue 1, it is related to builds being run by anonymous, not the daemon itself.

Comment: Hi Sagar, ah yes, you are right. I updated that part of my answer.

Comment: I needed to chown `/var/run/jenkins` and `/var/cache/jenkins` as well. Wouldn't work without that.

Comment: I still get an error: **Unable to create the home directory ‘JENKINS_HOME’. This is most likely a permission problem.**

Comment: I try to do it for Debian. Did not understand what have I to do with DAEMON_ARGS?

Comment: BT3, with DAEMON_ARGS, the change is to use set the 'name' parameter to $JENKINS_USER, which in the patch has been modified to be the username that you want jenkins to run as.
I wish I could be more helpful but if this is not working on Debian I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 10):

On Mac OS X, the way I enabled Jenkins to pull from my (private) Github repo is:

First, ensure that your user owns the Jenkins directory

```
sudo chown -R me:me /Users/Shared/Jenkins
```

Then edit the LaunchDaemon plist for Jenkins (at /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist) so that your user is the GroupName and the UserName:

```
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>me</string>
...
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>me</string>
```

Then reload Jenkins:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Then Jenkins, since it's running as you, has access to your ~/.ssh directory which has your keys.

Comment: Hi Commanda,
Additionally you will need to change permissions too 
`sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/folder`
Additionally uou will need to change the configuration file containing the jenkins user

Comment: @7dr3am7.. Which file permissions need to be changed? And where is the configuration and what changes need to be done? I am getting following error "stderr: Host key verification failed.
"

Comment: After performing the GroupName and UserName changes, i get this:
launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping): /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
nothing found to load
Which is not unexpected, how can someone just 'use' your account? there's no authorization anywhere. Jenkins probably needs your password or something, where can we put that?

Comment: What you need to do after adding your username to GroupName and UserName is this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63857/launchctldubious-permissions-on-file-problem-installing-jenkins
'god bless' other people for knowing- and wanting to know how OS'es work. because i'm glad i don't! what a ginormous amount of stupid rules and authorization stuff you should know to perform a simple operation.

Comment: You get a gold star. After a few hours of trying different solutions, this was the simplest to implement and it worked the first time.  I can go home now.

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to run Jenkins as you, I suggest you check out my Jenkins.app. An alternative, easy way to run Jenkins on Mac.

See https://github.com/stisti/jenkins-app/

Download it from https://github.com/stisti/jenkins-app/downloads

Comment: after hours of trying to run jenkins with its standard installation I gave up and switched to your solution. I will give more feedback as soon as I know how it goes.

Comment: Excellent!  Solved all of my configuration issues.  If you are on a Mac, this is the way to go!

Comment: After making and opening the app, I get: '“Jenkins” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.' Given that this answer and the project on github are both 5 years old, this seems like a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

To run jenkins as different user on ubuntu os you need to change below things.

Update below two lines in **/etc/default/jenkins** file

> JENKINS_USER=$USERNAME
>
> JENKINS_GROUP=$NAME

In our case we set user as ubuntu.

```
#JENKINS_USER=$NAME
#JENKINS_GROUP=$NAME
JENKINS_USER="ubuntu"
JENKINS_GROUP="ubuntu"
```

Update below two lines in **/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service** file

> User=jenkins
>
> Group=jenkins

In our case we set user as ubuntu.

```
#User=jenkins
#Group=jenkins
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
```

Change file ownership of jenkins owned folders.

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/lib/jenkins
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/cache/jenkins
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/log/jenkins
```

After above changes run below command to reload systemctl

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now you can restart jenkins

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

Answer (score -2):

you can integrate to LDAP or AD as well. It works well.

Comment: @shartp, how would one do that?

Comment: this may be a possible solution but more information would be useful about how and why it (might) work