# How to change home directory of Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, home-directory

Simple question: How to change the jenkins home directory location? By default it points to `/var/lib/jenkins` whereas I want it to point to `/home/jenkins`. I have changed my `$JENKINS_HOME` to `/home/jenkins` but it doesn't help me.

Comment: It seems after change environment variable, you still need to access jenkins home (e.g `localhost：8080/jenkins`) once, to make it takes effects, it will show `wait a while, ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jenkins usually runs with its own user,
so changing the home-dir of that user should do the job.

If not sure, simply run a test-job with a shell-command like 'id' or 'whoami' or 'env' to find the user that Jenkins uses.

Also, note that a message of "`Started by user anonymous`"  does not mean that Jenkins started as an anonymous user -
please see this related answers by [Sagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289812/sagar) and [Peter Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783051/peter-tran):

**[how to run jenkins as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692330/how-to-run-jenkins-as-a-different-user)**

Comment: Well but,what if its an anonymous User...In that case what should i look for..??

Comment: Depending on how Jenkins is initiated (as a service or else), you could change it's user. Also please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 26):

For me on Jenkins 2.7.2 on RHEL 7.2 after already starting jenkins and configuring a build, I needed to:

1) Change the jenkins user's home directory

```
sudo su -
service jenkins stop
vi /etc/passwd
#  change the /var/lib/jenkins to /home/jenkins or whatever
```

2) Change the setting in the start script to also find it

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
#   change the JENKINS_HOME to /home/jenkins or what ever
```

3)  Copy all the data to the new location (eg: /home/jenkins)

```
cd /home
cp -Rf /var/lib/jenkins .
chown -R jenkins:jenkins *
```

4) Start it back up

```
service jenkins start
```

And that seems to have done it for me.

Comment: There is no **/etc/sysconfig** on some systems.  It might be **/etc/init.d**

Comment: On Ubuntu Server it's /etc/default/jenkins.

Comment: **With step 1 and 3, you can combined to one command:**
`usermod -m -d /home/jenkins jenkins`

Comment: If these steps does not work then, mv the directory /var/lib/jenkins to /var/lib/jenkins_bkp, 
then create the link of the directory in /var/lib/jenkins and restart jenkins

Answer (score 8):

To change the Jenkins home directory you just need to setup the "JENKINS_HOME" environment variable to point to the new location.  You can also set the JENKINS_HOME as a system property or a JNDI environment entry as explained in the documentation.

[Jenkins Documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu server and using Jenkins version (2.277.4 +). I was able to change the Jenkins home directory by:

1. Changing the JENKINS_HOME value in `/etc/default/jenkins` to the desired folder name.
2. Update permission on the target folder so that `jenkins` user has read,write,execute permissions on the folder.

Answer (score 1):

All previous answers may not work for you if you are using **Jenkins version 2.332.1** or above and your Linux (Debian/RedHat) package installers using systemd to manage services.

**To Change the Jenkins Home:**

1. sudo systemctl stop jenkins
2. Run `sudo systemctl edit jenkins` ( Will work Ubuntu and Centos both )
3. And update the below lines: ( replace "/efs/jenkins-efs" with your new Jenkins home path"

   [Service]

   Environment="JENKINS_HOME=/efs/jenkins-efs"

   WorkingDirectory=/efs/jenkins-efs
4. sudo systemctl start jenkins
5. Validate Jenkins home through Jenkins UI

Reference link : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/systemd-services/
**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting the PATH thing but it doesn't seem to work as it probably has to be under Jenkins user which does not have a real unix user account.  I found the variable also accessible in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins which did the trick when I restarted Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

**[A]** Find your current jenkins home folder, if you are not aware where it is ? 
Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Check label 'Home directory' 
**[B]** To move current Jenkins home folder to a new directory. Follow below steps :-

1. Stop Jenkins service - by killing the process
2. Follow one of below approach to set new home folder for JENKINS.

   ```
   a) By default Jenkins home directory is set to ~/.jenkins
   b) "JENKINS_HOME" environment variable setup in operating system.
   c) "JENKINS_HOME" entry in JNDI environment.
   d) "JENKINS_HOME" system property to the servlet container.
           Tomcat context descriptor of the servlet, you can set below field in apache-tomcat-8.5.28/conf/context.xml :
           <Context ...>
             <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/path/to/jenkins_home/" type="java.lang.String"/>
           </Context>

   e)  If jenkins.war file is deployed in a tomcat server , then even appending below content in bin/catalina.sh will setup JENKINS_HOME.
               CATALINA_OPTS="-DJENKINS_HOME=/path_to/jenkins_home/"
   ```
3. Manually copy Jenkins home folder content from old to new home
   folder. (In windows , ctrl + c / v . In Unix ,
   use cp command) . Instead of moving, copy step is advised to keep one backup. Later we can delete old workspace.
4. Now start Jenkins, then It will pick the new home directory
   from the path mentioned in JENKINS_HOME variable.

   *Note: - Just by setting above variable "JENKINS_HOME" to a different path will not copy
   the files from current Jenkins home path to new one automatically. This copy step - you have to do it yourself, Manually.*

Answer (score 0):

Follow *steps*:

- `sudo su`
- `service jenkins stop`
- `nano /etc/default/jenkins`
- change `JENKINS_HOME` variable to whatever folder you want
- save it
- `service jenkins start*`