# Jenkins couldn't clone GIT repository (MacOS X 10.8.2)

Tags: macos, git, jenkins

System: MacOS, standard Jenkins installation.
I can clone repository from my user. But Jenkins - can't neither from Git, not from GitHub (my key is added to Git and GitHub). I receive: "stderr: Host key verification failed."

I've copied my key into /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.ssh - but still no luck :( Maybe I've copied it to incorrect place?
Generate ssh key from Jenkins is not an option for me.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a public repo? If so a workaround is to use Github's "Git Read-Only" link (e.g `git://github.com/myuser/myrepo.git`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually related to permissions, as Jenkins' process runs as user 'jenkins'.

See here: **[How to run jenkins as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692330/how-to-run-jenkins-as-a-different-user)** -
especially the answers of *[Sagar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6694060)* and *[Peter Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936427)* .

Cheers

Comment: there is no user jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, the problem (at least first) is with host key verification. The first time you connect to an ssh server, ssh client will prompt you to check and accept the host key. (Of course no-one does that, so I don't know why it bothers...)

You could

```
sudo -u jenkins -i
```

and then

```
ssh git@github.com
```

and then reply to the prompt. Alternatively you can disable host key checking. Look up StrictHostKeyChecking in **man ssh_config**.