# How can I point Jenkins to another .jenkins home directory?

Tags: jenkins

I have the working /.jenkins folder under a specific user in home on Linux. I want to start Jenkins with another user, but re-use the .jenkins folder of the other user. How can I do this? Jenkins offers some instructions but I don't get it :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think this can help you out.

Set an Environment Variable `JENKINS_HOME` pointing to the `.jenkins` folder and run the Jenkins command.

---

The shell should be like

```
export JENKINS_HOME=/usr/jhon/.jenkins

java -jar jenkins.war
```

---

The batch should be like

```
  SET JENKINS_HOME=C:\users\jhon\.jenkins

 java -jar jenkins.war
```

---

The `Powershell` should be like

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JENKINS_HOME", "${PWD}\.jenkins")
java -jar jenkins.war
```

**This will set your home directory to the `current-working-directory + './jenkins'`**

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I needed to run a foreground slave server on a machine that already had Jenkins and so setting the ENV var in the script just before launch worked.

Comment: if the jenkins war is running on a tomcat, kill the server and restart after exporting JENKINS_HOME.

Comment: This will cause an error: **Unable to create the home directory ‘JENKINS_HOME’. This is most likely a permission problem.**

Comment: Using the Java option -DJENKINS_HOME=... can be even more compact

Answer (score 12):

Here are the options you have:

a) Assuming you're deploying Jenkins into Tomcat,you can do the following:

In your catalina.home/conf/localhost/jenkins.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="/home/enomad/projects/jenkins/jenkins-master/war/target/jenkins" path="" reloadable="true">
 <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/home/enomad/projects/jenkins-home"
         type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

b) You can **export the JENKINS_HOME=toWhateveryouwant** as mentioned by Harsha in the previous post

c) You can extend your **JAVA_OPTS** params and add **-DJENKINS_HOME=**/path/to/jenkins_home/ as described here: [Jenkins Mailing list](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Configuring-Jenkins-td3800471.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Particularly helpful if you have to use tomcat service starters in Windows environments and need to have two Jenkins instances during migration.

Answer (score 2):

I am using jenkins 1.639 as a war deployed on tomcat 7.0.67 . My JENKINS_HOME is set to /home/hims/jenkins

This is the entry of my setenv.sh file under /tomcat/bin directory

**export CATALINA_OPTS="-DJENKINS_HOME=/home/hims/jenkins"**

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins was not taking JENKINS_HOME env variable i set for some weird reason.

The i added this line in tomcat start up script(/etc/init.d/tomcat).

```
    $export JENKINS_HOME=/path/to/jenkins_home/
```

Now jenkins points to the new jenkins home :) This will be useful especially when you install jenkins on cloud. (on an Ec2 or eucalyptus intance)

Reference: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Or you can modify the .bashrc so that it sets the environment variable everytime you start a console, that is, if you are using bash to start Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

In Tomcat 5 you can modify tomcat.conf and add the path:

export JAVA_OPTS="-DJENKINS_HOME=/home/jenkins"

Restart Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you need to set the permissions for those files to be accessed by the new user.

See here: **[How to run jenkins as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692330/how-to-run-jenkins-as-a-different-user)** -
especially the answers of *[Sagar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6694060)* and *[Peter Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936427)* .

Cheers