# Jenkins not loading with correct config.xml file

Tags: jenkins, config, jenkins-cli

I am having a strange issue with my Jenkins (1.646) were by when I run;

`Java -jar %~dp0jenkins.war% --httpPort=XXXX` from the command line Jenkins runs and it seems to create a whole new instance under my user folder and doesn't read any files located under `C:\.jenkins` and importantly completely misses the;

> config.xml file (located .jenkins)

Thankful for any help/pointers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I point Jenkins to another .jenkins home directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139168/how-can-i-point-jenkins-to-another-jenkins-home-directory)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix this issue by setting the environment variable `JENKINS_HOME` to `c:\.jenkins`.

When I then run the `java -jar %~dp0jenkins.war%....` batch file it now correctly picks up the config.xml