# How to run two instances of Jenkins on one Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I've been tasked to run two instances of Jenkins on one tomcat web server.  In my server.xml file, I have setup 2 service names with different ports, host, etc. for the two Jenkins.

However, the problem I'm running into is they are both using the same JENKINS_HOME directory.  The first instance, I'm letting it use the default location (in my case /home/jenkins/.jenkins).  The second instance, I want it to use /home/jenkins/.j2.  However, I'm having difficulty doing that.

Snippet from my server.xml file

```
<!-- first instance of Jenkins.  it is using the default Jenkins home and working fine -->

    <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>

<!-- trying to force it to use the second Jenkins home for the second  instance of Jenkins -->
<!-- got this trick from another stackoverflow answer -->
      <Context docBase="/glide/bigdata/tomcat/webapps2/jenkins.war" path="" reloadable="true">
         <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/home/jenkins/.j2" type="java.lang.String"/>
      </Context>

<!-- second instance of Jenkins.  not working nicely -->
  <Service name="j2">
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="j2" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps2" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
```

I can see in the catalina.out log file that it is expanding the respective war files but that the JENKINS_HOME is still /home/jenkins/.jenkins for both.
What do I need to do to make the second instance use the second Jenkins home?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this may have no effect cus i haven’t setup jenkins a long time and have no idea what the setting is for but have you tried using different redirect ports for each?

Comment: @mad.meesh, no, it didn't change anything  =(  the first instance is the default settings so I left that redirect port number the same.  I changed the second instance and it change anything for the better.

Comment: ah. didn’t think it would. well, i remember there being another config file... a more bash-like config that is. am i remembering that correctly? you should be able change the variable there. the thing is `JENKINS_HOME` is akin to a bash-like variable and in the snippet you post here i don’t see the variable declared at all

Comment: i mean i see you try to set it using `Environment name` but  like i said i thought this was done elsewhere

Comment: @mad.meesh, so the default JENKINS_HOME is /home/someuser/.jenkins.    I'm letting the first instance take that, which is fine by me.  The second instance is where I want to change the JENKINS_HOME to be a different directory since these are supposed to be two separate instances of the application.  I think I see what you're saying, there is a file called "setenv.sh" and declare JENKINS_HOME in there.  The problem is, I don't want both to use the same home directory.  I want both to use different JENKINS_HOME directories

Comment: This is the answer I got this tip from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14155014/1631414

Comment: ok i see. well i looked this up and one thing i saw that’s not in your config is the attribute: `override=false` ... have you tried that?

Comment: @mad.meesh, yeah, I think I want override=true...that and setting to false didn't work  :D  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Environment_Entries

Comment: heh ok. well what you should try is to do the simplest thing first which is doing what you want with one instance first, ie, forcing the home folder for one instance. then when you’re able to do that, add the second instance. i say this because the example you linked is the solution to a different but related issue, that (obviously) being they simply want to change the home dir with instance.

Answer (score 0):

Update context value by adding **application-name.xml** file to **apache-tomcat-x.x.x/conf/Catalina/localhost**

```
<Context ...>
  <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/path/to/jenkins_home/" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

Refer https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Tomcat

**PS:** Initially you may have to copy the set up file from **.jenkins/*** to **/path/to/jenkins_home/**

Same way you could create separate instance by changing the application name.