# Update Jenkins Home Directory

Tags: jenkins, home-directory

1. I'm using Mac, I have copied all the contents from old locaiton to new location. Initial Home directory is Users/xxxxxx/Jenkins/Home and after changing configure system in Home directory still points at old location
2. export Jenkins_Home=/Volumes/DATA/Jenkins_Home and also updated .zshrc profile file added the above.
3. Still didn't change to the new location after restarting.

Comment: It's [JENKINS_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152537/598141); case matters.

Comment: I have given this path in .zshrc profile.                                                                
export JENKINS_HOME=/Volumes/DATA/JenkinsHome/