# Run jenkins job as another user

Tags: linux, jenkins

I Installed jenkins using a guide, and that guide created a "jenkins" user in the server and apparently runs the jenkins server under it.

All my setup on the server (virtual env, python package installations) is for a different user ("ci-user"). Is there any way for me to run my jobs as "ci_user" instead of as "jenkins"? I'd like to avoid doing all the setup again for the "jenkins" user.

Comment: You mean on startup or run it yourself

Comment: Can you provide a link to the guide? That would give a lot of info about how you are set up now. It would depend which distribution and init daemon you are using.

Comment: @nbering I have written an article for Jenkins setup on Ubuntu. You can  have a look on https://qamag.net/setup-ubuntu-jenkins-master/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `JENKINS_USER` variable in `etc/default/jenkins` file. You could change it to ci_user, then you will need to change the ownership of several folders and reboot the machine.

```
chown -R ci_user /var/lib/jenkins
chown -R ci_user /var/log/jenkins
chown -R ci_user /var/cache/jenkins
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936427/7624566)