# How to run Jenkins jobs as user other than "anonymous?"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm logged in as my user account (an admin) in Jenkins. I have project-based security on, with no access to "anonymous" user. Now when I run my Jenkins jobs manually, or via cron, the jobs run as "anonymous" user. How can I set my jobs to run as "jenkins" user by default?

Note I read [Run jenkins job as another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634565/run-jenkins-job-as-another-user), and the the default user is `/etc/default/jenkins` is `jenkins`, and that user owns the Jenkins files.

I mean why are my jobs "Running as anonymous" (seen on a job's console session) when I run them as my user, an admin user, or triggered by a timer?

Comment: Where are you seeing "anonymous" user? Are you jobs running on the Controller or nodes (or co-located nodes)? What platform (Win/Lnx/Mac)?

Comment: @IanW thanks for replying. On a job's console session, I see first line `Started by user myuser`, 2nd line `Running as anonymous`. My master node is on a Ubuntu Linux, and I have both Linxu and Windows build nodes where my jobs run, and it's exhibited on either build node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

In `Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security`, toward the middle of page there's a section called `Access Control For Builds`. The `Strategy` was set to `Run as anonymous`, I set it to `Run as SYSTEM`.