# Can I tell jenkins agent to execute job under a configured user?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm training a MacBook to be a jenkins agent for automation testing. On the MacBook, I logged in as user `bob` and installed everything needed (npm, yarn, xcode etc). Then I connected to a remote master using `Java Web Start`.

Because I launched the java thing in user `bob`, I assume jenkins pipeline jobs will also be under `bob`, which seems true - `whoami` command in pipeline echos `bob`. However, all dependencies cannot be found. If I `echo $PATH` I see a completely different result compared to `echo $PATH` directly on the MacBook.

I googled a bit, the problem might be that Jenkins create a new shell on everyjob. Can I tell jenkins pipeline to not to do this? I want the pipeline to use everything I configured manually for `bob`.

EDIT:

The main problem is jenkins pipeline's user has a different PATH. I ended up using environment directives to specify which path to use.

```
environment {
    PATH = "/Users/bappo/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin:$PATH"
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run jenkins as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692330/how-to-run-jenkins-as-a-different-user)

Comment: Hmm not an exact duplicate - in my case I manually configured user `bob` on the macbook, and jenkins pipeline also executes under user `bob`, but with different `$PATH`. I ended up using jenkins environment directives to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What where you trying to configure? If you have parameters/configuration for your pipeline I strongly recommend to use pipeline [parameters](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters). They can either configured manually (including default values) or from the jenkinsfile.

[example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Parametrized-pipelines)